# "route add default -iface em1" in rc.conf on FreeBSD

Tags: networking, routing, freebsd

I have two NICs on my FreeBSD server, which are set up like this in `rc.conf`:

```
ifconfig_em0="10.0.0.1    netmask 255.255.255.0"        # LAN NIC
ifconfig_em1="DHCP"                                     # WAN NIC
```

This setup doesn't give any default route, only (assuming `123.123.123.123` is the WAN IP of `em1`):

```
10.0.0.0/24         ---> em0
123.123.123.123/32  ---> em1
```

When I try to ping WAN IPs like `8.8.8.8`, I get `No route to host`. (Why? Doesn't `123.123.123.123/32` mean almost the same as `default`?) Anyway, I can run `add route default -iface em1`, and then WAN IPs are directed through `em1`, as they should.

---

**How do I make interface `em1` the default, reboot-persistent route for my system? I.e., how can I say `add route default -iface em1` in `rc.conf`?** *(I have to make the route interface-specific and not specific to the interface's IP, because the IP of em1 is dynamically given by my ISP.)*

---

I've tried the following without success:

```
static_routes="mydefault"
route_mydefault="default -iface em1"
```

and

```
defaultrouter="-iface em1"
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch NIC's so that em0 would be the one who use DHCP and em1 is the one with the static IP? That would probably solve this in a easy way.

Comment: @pauska Really?! em0 is considered as default before em1? Sounds like a tempting, easy answer to this nuisance. Anyways, I'd like to know if there's a solution without switching roles of the two NICs.

Comment: re "Doesn't 123.123.123.123/32 mean almost the same as default?" No. The default is 0.0.0.0/0. The /32 means narrowing to one host only.

Comment: Did you check, that your ISP sends a Defaultgw with DHCP? Do you use any custom dhclient configuration? try to run dhclient manually and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah - totally rewritten because I misread the question!

It sounds like your route may not be coming up because `em1` isn't up and ready when the rc scripts go to set the default router.  You can use the `defaultroute_delay` option in rc.conf to make the system wait a while before bringing up the default routes.

Also like @arved said you may want to make sure your ISP is sending the router information in their DHCP leases -- If you want to use their gateway they *should* be specifying one, otherwise you will only be able to reach devices on the subnet they specify.

Comment: Thanks for the `defaultroute_delay`-tip! I'll check that one out.