# FreeBSD save default route with gateway on different subnet

Tags: linux-networking, freebsd, truenas

I'm trying to set up a default gateway which is not on the same subnet of my freebsd (freenas) machine.
According to [THIS](https://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-help/2006/12/15/0000.html) article, there is way :

```
route add -host <<GW_IP>> -link eth0 -iface
route add default -ifa <<eth0ip>> <<GW_IP>>
```

However , appereantly, these commands are not persistent.
In fact everytime I `service netif restart` my changes get lost.
How can I make these changes permanent?

***EDIT***

Here is the output of `netstat -rn` after `route add` commands
[image]

When I restart netif, the first two entries get removed.

Comment: You might take a look at [this linked Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/355929/)

Comment: I've looked into it, but it's not solving my problem

Comment: Could anyone explain how host and it's default gateway could be not on the same subnet? that beats me...

Comment: @user1700494 I have e static public IP assigned to vm in the cloud. The gateway is not on the same subnet.

Comment: Pls post output of `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn`

Comment: @user1700494 see edit :) thank you for your time!